# Hibernate schema-validation fails on fixed-length character field

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I get the following error when validating a set of JPA-entities against a database-schema with Hibernate:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in public.postal_code for column country. Found: bpchar, expected: bytea
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
```

The underlying database is PostgreSQL 9.1 and the relevant database-tables are defined thus:

```
CREATE TABLE country
(
  code_alpha2 character(2) NOT NULL, -- ISO 3166 alpha2 code
  code_alpha3 character(3), -- ISO 3166 alpha3 code
  CONSTRAINT country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (code_alpha2)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE postal_code
(
  country character(2) NOT NULL, -- ISO 3166 alpha2 country-code
  code character varying(12) NOT NULL, -- Postal code proper
  CONSTRAINT postal_code_pk PRIMARY KEY (country, code),
  CONSTRAINT country_fk FOREIGN KEY (country)
      REFERENCES country (code_alpha2) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The entities are defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="code_alpha2", columnDefinition="bpchar")
    private String codeAlpha2;

    @Column(name="code_alpha3", columnDefinition="bpchar")
    private String codeAlpha3;

    public Country() {
    }

    public String getCodeAlpha2() {
        return this.codeAlpha2;
    }

    public void setCodeAlpha2(String codeAlpha2) {
        this.codeAlpha2 = codeAlpha2;
    }

    public String getCodeAlpha3() {
        return this.codeAlpha3;
    }

    public void setCodeAlpha3(String codeAlpha3) {
        this.codeAlpha3 = codeAlpha3;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(PostalCodePK.class)
@Table(name="postal_code")
public class PostalCode implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country country;

    @Id
    private String code;

    public PostalCode() {
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Finally, the class defining the primary key for postal_code:

```
@Embeddable
public class PostalCodePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(columnDefinition="bpchar")
    private Country country;

    private String code;

    public PostalCodePK() {
    }
    public Country getCountry() 
        return this.country;
    }
    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof PostalCodePK)) {
            return false;
        }
        PostalCodePK castOther = (PostalCodePK)other;
        return 
            this.country.equals(castOther.country)
            && this.code.equals(castOther.code);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.country.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.code.hashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Why is Hibernate expecting a bytea in the column country? And how can I convince the validator to accept the schema as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: Hibernate was treating the dependency not as an entity, but as an object to be serialised and stored as such in the database. The solution was to change the data-type of the field "country" in PostalCodePK to String and to switch to using an embedded ID while adding the annotation @MapsId to the field "country" in PostalCode:

```
    @EmbeddedId
    PostalCodePK id;

    @MapsId("country")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country country;
```